# Batch script for user/password read from file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

My script works perfectly but I need to share this script in the company for all users, the problem is that the user and password (my credentials are in the cmd line ) like :

```
mycmd.exe -h "user:mypassword@10.0.0.1:8086"
```

I need to make this script to read user and password from a file (.txt, .ini), where everyone puts their credentials in the file.

I have tried to find something similar on the internet but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this :

Data.ini :

```
UserID=Toto
Password=1234
```

Auth.bat:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (Data.ini) do set %%a
mycmd.exe -h "%UserID%:%Password%@10.0.0.1:8086"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data.bat**

```
set UserID=abcd
set Password=1234
set Server=xyz
```

**Auth.bat**

```
call D:\Scripts\Data.bat
sqlplus %UserID%/%Password%@%Server%
```